# Vue.js - Initialise a variable on page load

Tags: javascript, html, vue.js

I am currently developing a webapp using Vue.js and JavaScript, and am in the process of consolidating the .js files for performance reasons. Before combining the .js files, I had a separate .js file for each static html page. In each .js file is a method named initialise() which is called on the created hook which calls other initialising methods that initialises the relevant variables. But now that I've combined the .js files, I need some sort of way of calling only the initialising methods relevant to the current page.

One way that I've tried to do this is to have my initialise() method like this:

```
initialise: function() {
    if (this.currentPage=="profile") {
        this.getNightmode();
        this.getProfile();
        this.getTaskTypes();
    } else if (this.currentPage=="postRegistration") {
        this.getSignUpMethod();
        this.getAccountType();
        this.getTaskTypes();
    }
}
```

And a vue variable called `currentPage` which I attempt initialise on page load, in the html body tag, like this `<body v-on:load="currentPage='profile'">`

`v-on:load`, however, does not seem to work. Is there any way to initialise a vue variable according to the current page?

Comment: Have you used Vue Router in the application ? I think it is a better option.

Comment: see lifecycle hooks part of this page ... https://vuejs.org/v2/guide/instance.html

Comment: Yes I am already calling initialise() with the created hook, I just need the initialisation to be specific to the page that the user is currently on

Answer (score 0):

I've figured it out. Using the created hook I also initialised `currentPage` with `window.location.pathname`, which initialises `currentPage` the current URL pathname. My initialising method now looks like

```
initialise: function() {
    if (this.currentPage=="/profile.html") {
        this.getNightmode();
        this.getProfile();
        this.getTaskTypes();
    } else if (this.currentPage=="/post_registration.html") {
        this.getSignUpMethod();
        this.getAccountType();
        this.getTaskTypes();
    }
}
```

And this calls the correct initialising methods according to the page.